# How to make edit form appear in proper place?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I tried to make this edit form appear when I click edit button using ajax jquery. It's working, but the form not appear in proper place.

This is a pict before edit button clicked

[image]

This is a pict after edit button clicked

[image]

**js**

```
$(".btn-comment").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url : '../edit-form.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : 'id='+id,
            success : function(msg) {
            //  $("#container-positive").hide().load('form-edit.php').fadeIn(1000);
                $("#display-edit-form").hide().fadeIn(1000).html(msg);
            }
        });

    });
```

**edit-form.php**

```
<?php
include_once '../config.inc/koneksi.php';

$id_comment=$_POST['id'];
$stmt=$db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_comments WHERE id_comment=:id_comment");
$stmt->execute(array(":id_comment"=>$id_comment));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
<form id="edit-form" method="post" action="">
 <div class="form-group">
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" required><?php echo $row->description; ?></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update-profile">Kirim</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn-cancel">Batal</button>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**index.php**

```
  <?php }

    while($rowcom=$comment->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $profile ="../../profile/".$rowcom->username;
    $title =  clean_url($rowcom->title);
    ?>
   <tr>
   <td >
   <div class="media">
     <div class="media-left-detail">
    <div class="space">
    <a href="<?php echo $profile ?>">
   <img class="media-object" src="../<?php echo $rowcom->image;?>" alt="...">
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="media-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <h4 class="name"><a href="<?php echo $profile ?>"><?php echo $rowcom->username; ?></a><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> <?php  echo date('H:i', strtotime($rowcom->created_date));?> &nbsp;<?php echo date("d F Y", strtotime($rowcom->created_date));?></span></h4>
     <p class="text"><?php  echo $rowcom->description;?></p>
     <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="display-edit-form">
</div>
 <ul class="icon-list">
<li><a class="btn btn-comment"id="<?php echo $rowcom->id_comment;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="btn btn-delete" id="<?php echo $rowcom->id_comment;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `index.php`, it looks like you'll have a `<div id="display-edit-form"></div>` for each comment entry.  In your ajax success function,

```
success : function(msg) {
    $("#display-edit-form").hide().fadeIn(1000).html(msg);
}
```

What part of that function decides which `div` to put the form in?

UPDATE:

To clarify, this is what you have:

```
<div>
    <div>first comment...</div>
    <div id="display-edit-form"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>second comment...</div>
    <div id="display-edit-form"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>third comment...</div>
    <div id="display-edit-form"></div>
</div>
```

There are three `div` elements that all match the jQuery expression `$(#display-edit-form)`.  You're already accessing the `id` of the button that was clicked, but you're not actually using it anywhere.  You'd need something like this:

```
$(".btn-comment").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url : '../edit-form.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : 'id='+id,
        success : function(msg) {
            $(".display-edit-form[data-id=" + id + "]").hide().fadeIn(1000).html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

and your `index.php` would have this:

```
<div class="display-edit-form" data-id="<?php echo $rowcom->id_comment ?>">
</div>
```

This way, you'd end up with something like:

```
<div>
    <!-- first comment -->
    <div class="display-edit-form" data-id="1">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- second comment -->
    <div class="display-edit-form" data-id="2">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- third comment -->
    <div class="display-edit-form" data-id="3">
    </div>
</div>
```

and your code can distinguish between the different comment form `div`s.

Comment: in display-edit-form..
like this..
<div id="display-edit-form">
<form id="edit-form">
</form>
</div>

Comment: Right - but your page has multiple elements `<div id="display-edit-form">`.  How does the function know which of those `div`s to use?

Comment: I've edited index.php.
The link I put in <ul class="icon-list">function</ul>
But it's not working, when I clicked the last comment there, edit form appeared in first comment.. it's always same as I clicked edit button in every comment,, edit form always be in first comment..

Comment: See my clarifications above.

Comment: thank you so much.. it's working perfectly...
But I have one question, how to hide the text(<p class="text"><?php  echo $rowcom->description;?></p>) when edit form apear..? Thank you so much...

Comment: I've found the answer...
I use this one.. $(".text[data-id=" + id + "]").hide();
Thank you so much for helping me.. You save my life..